# net/http: TLS handshake timeout

Tags: vmware, terraform

while building with terraform plan i am getting the error. This is my .tf file:

```
provider "vsphere" {
  user           = "aaa"
  password       = "aaa"
  vsphere_server = "172.22.1.139"
  allow_unverified_ssl = "true"
}

resource "vsphere_folder" "frontend" {
  path = "VirtualMachines"
  datacenter = "A2MS0110-VMFS5"
}

resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "FIRST_VM" {
  name   = "FIRST_VM"
  vcpu   = 1
  memory = 2048
  datacenter = "A2MS0110-VMFS5"
  network_interface {
    label = "VM Network"
  }
  disk {
    datastore = "A2MS0110-VMFS5"
    vmdk = "/demo2"
  }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
* provider.vsphere: Error setting up client: Post https://172.22.1.139/sdk: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
```

Is this network problem or configuration error?

Comment: Your configuration is correct. It seems like you have networking issues between a host with terraform and vSphere. Can you access   https://172.22.1.139 from a host with terraform using `curl` for example?

Comment: i gave "curl https:172.22.1.139"  . It's giving "curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to 172.22.1.139:443
" error.